# DFT code on Matlab does not work as intended

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, dft

I am trying to implement a basic DFT algorithm on Matlab.
I simply use in phase and quadrature components of a sine wave with phase modulation(increasing frequency a.k.a chirp). I do compare my results with fft command of Matlab. My code gives the same results whenever there is no phase modulation(pure sine). Whenever I add chirp modulation, results differ. For example, when I use a chirp with some bandwidth around a carrier, the expected results should be a frequency distribution of chirp bandwidth starting from carrier frequency. However, I get a copy of that result backwards starting from carrier frequency as well. You can use my code below without modifying anything. Figure 5 is my result and figure 6 is the expected result. Carrier is 256 Hz with a 10Hz bandwidth of chirp. You can see the code below. The important part is for loop where I take dft of my signal. Also uou can see my dft result below.

[image]

```
close all;
clear all;
%% signal generation
t = (0:0.0001:1); % 1 second window
f = 256; %freq of input signal in hertz
bw = 10; % bandwidth sweep of signal
phaseInput = 2*pi*t*bw.*t;                  
signalInput = sin(2*pi*f*t + phaseInput);   %input signal
inphase = sin(2*pi*f*t).*cos(phaseInput);    %inphase component
quadrature = cos(2*pi*f*t).*sin(phaseInput); %quadrature component

figure
plot(t,signalInput,'b',t,inphase,'g',t,quadrature,'r');
title('Input Signal');
xlabel('Time in seconds');
ylabel('Amplitude');

%% sampling signal previously generated
Fs = 1024; %sampling freq
Ts = (0:1/Fs:1);%sample times for 1 second window

sPhase = 2*pi*Ts*bw.*Ts;
sI = sin(2*pi*f*Ts).*cos(sPhase);
sQ = cos(2*pi*f*Ts).*sin(sPhase);

hold on;
plot(Ts,sI+sQ,'b*',Ts,sI,'g*',Ts,sQ,'r*');


fftSize = Fs; %Using all samples in dft
sampleIdx = (0:1:fftSize-1)';

sampledI = sI(1:fftSize)';
sampledQ = sQ(1:fftSize)';

figure;
plot(sampleIdx,sampledI,sampleIdx,sampledQ);
title('Sampled IQ Components');

%% DFT Calculation
dftI = zeros(fftSize,1);
dftQ = zeros(fftSize,1);

for w = 0:fftSize-1
    %exp(-2*pi*w*t) = cos(2*pi*w*t) - i*sin(2*pi*w*t)
    cI = cos(2*pi*w*sampleIdx/fftSize);     %correlation cos
    cQ = -sin(2*pi*w*sampleIdx/fftSize);    %correlation sin
    dftI(w+1) = sum(sampledI.*cI - sampledQ.*cQ); %
    dftQ(w+1) = sum(sampledI.*cQ + sampledQ.*cI);
end;

figure;
plot(Fs*sampleIdx/fftSize,dftI);
title('DFT Inphase');
xlabel('Hertz');
figure
plot(Fs*sampleIdx/fftSize,dftQ);
title('DFT Quadrature');
xlabel('Hertz');


figure;
plot(Fs*sampleIdx/fftSize,sqrt(dftQ.^2+dftI.^2));

%% For comparison
sampledInput = sin(2*pi*f*Ts + sPhase);

Y = fft(sampledInput(1:1024),1024);
Pyy = Y.*conj(Y)/1024;
f = (0:1023);
figure;
plot(f,Pyy)
title('Power spectral density')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
```

Comment: i don't understand `sI = sin(2*pi*f*Ts).*cos(sPhase); sQ = cos(2*pi*f*Ts).*sin(sPhase);` it seems right when i change them to `sI = sin(2*pi*f*Ts+sPhase)+cos(2*pi*f*Ts+sPhase); sQ = cos(2*pi*f*Ts+sPhase)+sin(2*pi*f*Ts+sPhase);`

Comment: Take a look at wiki for iq decomposition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-phase_and_quadrature_components

Comment: my second comment about `Hilbert transform` is not true, so i deleted it. maybe i should review these lessons :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason lies in the fact that two different signals will definitely give your two different frequency spectrums. check out the code below, you will find that the input of the dft algorithm you actually gave is `sampledI+jsampledQ`. as a result, what you are doing here is NOT merely decomposing your original signal into `In-phase and quadrature components`, instead, you are doing `Hilbert transform` here -- to change a `real` signal into a `complex` one.

```
cI = cos(2*pi*w*sampleIdx/fftSize);     %correlation cos
cQ = -sin(2*pi*w*sampleIdx/fftSize);    %correlation sin
dftI(w+1) = sum(sampledI.*cI - sampledQ.*cQ); %
dftQ(w+1) = sum(sampledI.*cQ + sampledQ.*cI);
```

so the `sampledInput` for comparison should be `sampledInput = sI+1i*sQ;`.

Comment: Yes you are right, my mistake was including carrier harmonic in I Q components as well. The right way should be taking only phase side of my signal for IQ decomposition. Thanks for your help Gnimuc Key.